# String not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect

Tags: c#

I'm getting this STRING value from a code written in the UK

```
"15:11 PM Friday, February 20, 2"
```

and try to convert it to a DateTime using **Convert.ToDateTime("string value")**

I get an Exception stating that
**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime because the day of week was incorrect.**

The 20th was a Friday on February 2015.
Is the problem the fact that we are missing the YEAR?

Comment: What format did you use to parse it..?

Comment: a straight Convert.ToDateTime("string")

Comment: looks like your year was cut off, unless you are working in the year 2.

Comment: Dammm ..I assume 2 was February. OK, I'll check on that.

Comment: Usually to the right of the rest of the date.  In this case, it is a 2, which is either wrong or just unusual.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The return value is the result of invoking the `DateTime.Parse` method on value using the formatting information in a `DateTimeFormatInfo` object that is initialized for the current culture.

Look at the formats in there and you'll very likely not find one without the year specified. Add your own to it or parse it with a format directly.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies on the software the produces the actual UK date as there is no year. Maybe when it converts it.

Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 2):

Technically the error message is correct - the day of the week is incorrect if you are dealing with the year `2`.

The UK uses dates just like the rest of the civilised world (I exclude the USA and any other country that uses mm/dd/yy from the set of "civilised"), so I would be checking why you are missing the rest of the year.

Comment: It seems that the problem lies on the software the produces the actual UK date as there is no year. Maybe when it converts it.

Thanks for the heads-up.